# Which .NET class does represent the main CONTROLLER class for WebForms?

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, controller

I was studying a bit of Java, when I was taught about a way to implement a **controller class**, whose resposibility is to redirect the request to an Action, which perfoms a specified work. That was the way I learnt;

```
@Override
protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {
        String clazz = req.getRequestURI().replaceAll(req.getContextPath() + "/", "").replaceAll(".java", "");
        ((Action)Class.forName("com.myProject.actions." + clazz).newInstance()).execute(req, res);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I know that WebForms also works with **HANDLERS**, which are kind of actions. For example, each .aspx page inherits from a Page object which is a handler for that specified page.

What I couldn't figure out is, which class does get request first and translate it to the specified action (page handler)? Is it a WebForms feature(implementation) or its a IIS resposibility? So, which class represent the main controller for WebForms?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Check out  ASP.Net MVC (second framework in ASP.Net) - may work better for you if need to port code written in controller-action fashion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest reading about **[HttpApplication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.aspx)** class, especially **[MapRequestHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.maprequesthandler.aspx)**.

> The MapRequestHandler event is used by
>   the ASP.NET infrastructure to
>   determine the request handler for the
>   current request. For more information,
>   see How to: Register HTTP Handlers.

[ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview for IIS 7.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In webforms, the code behind page is the controller. While that aspx page is the view.

Comment: Ok, but who handles the redirect to a given .aspx page? The point is, who first gets the http request and decide which .aspx code behind are gonna do the work...!?

Comment: I think Renato is looking for information on which code selects actual page for each request.